# Best way to layout a list of data across a page

Tags: php, html, css

I'm returning database results in PHP using a foreach loop ideally, I would like to lay the result set out in three columns.

```
<?php 
foreach ($departments as $department) { ?>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="departments[]" 
       value="<?php echo $department->id; ?>">
    <label><?php echo $department->name; ?></label>
<?php 
} ?>
```

At the moment this simply lists the result set in a single vertical line. What options do I have to span the list across the page? I'm guessing some form of HTML table or CSS? Whats the best way to incorporate that into a PHP foreach loop?

Comment: either loop <tr><td> or <li> or <div> ... its your personal choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are not really the solution. Since the number of checkboxes are not constant, you cannot have a fixed table structure without using javascript overhead to align them properly. Lists might be a good solution.

Even better solution is to use divs with `float: left`

```
<?php foreach($departments as $department) { ?>
    <div class="width-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="departments[]" value="<?php echo $department->id; ?>" />
        <span><?php echo $department->name; ?></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Here, `width-4` is the div that helps align your checkboxes. CSS is given below.

```
.width-4 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

Be careful if you are adding padding, margin or border to/inside `width-4`. In that case, you need to use another container div inside `width-4` and add padding, border or margin to it.

Advantage of this layout is that after 4 checkboxes, subsequent checkboxes automatically move to next line. These can be easily styled by styling `width-4`.

Comment: i like the idea of this solution really simple and gives great results

Answer (score 1):

List or a table would do. For a table use

```
  <table>
  <tr>
  <?php foreach ($departments as $department): ?>
  <td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="departments[]" value="<?php echo $department->id; ?>">
  <label><?php echo $department->name; ?></label>
  </td>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: TR's have to be inside the loop else he may got HELL to long TR .

Answer (score 0):

Just make a list :)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="departments">
<?php foreach ($departments as $department) { ?>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="departments[]" value="<?php echo $department->id; ?>">
        <label><?php echo $department->name; ?></label>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.departments li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**See example here :** http://jsfiddle.net/7a88w1vb/